# No speed upgrade observed using Cython

Tags: python, cython

I tried to use cython version of my python code but no speed upgrade was observed

the python code is

```
def myFunction(x,y,z):
    for i in range(x):
        answer = [x**10, y**10,z**10] 
        print(answer)
```

whereas the cython file's code is

```
def myFunction(int x, int y, int z):
    cdef int i
    cdef int answer[3]
    for i in range(x):
        answer = [x**10, y**10,z**10] 
        print(answer)
```

its working after cythonizing it using setup file. but the execution speed of both are almost same. Can anyone point me what could be missing or wrong?

Comment: 1) Have you looked at the annotated html from Cython to see what it thinks might be inefficient. 2) The time is probably going to be spent printing (which is typically fairly slow). Cython isn't likely to help with that.

Comment: thanks man, the problem was that it involved printing.

Comment: If you really need to print within the function call, you can consider using C's `printf` function instead. This can be imported into cython using `from libc.stdio cimport *`. This could save some slight python function call overhead and conversions from C ints to python ints. That being said, it only provided a < 2x speed improvement from the cython `myFunction` version you provide.